# How can I rewrite URLs in Google Analytics 4 to recognize foreign languages like Bulgarian?

Tags: google-analytics-4

[Strange urls in GA4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM8E9.png) GA4 can't recognise URLs in foreign languages like Bulgarian. How can I make URLs vaiable again?

The website for the client is in Bulgarian but Google translates the URLs as seen in the image. The page names are shown correctly in Bulgarian.

I am trying to make analyses with the URLs and put the data into Looker Studio. Currently, the data is hard to filter due to the symbols in the URLs. Is there a way to rewrite the URLs like the way URLs are shown in the browser?

Comment: Can you attach the image?

Comment: This is not a programming question and would be better asked at [webmasters.se]

Answer (score 0):

One method can be read the info from back-end and then decode it.
Supposing you can read your Google Analytics Data from [google-analytics-data documentation](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-analytics-data/latest/overview), for example using in `JAVA` programming language URLDecode  would be :
instead of **encodedString** you should write the value of your specific dimension which is containing the URL.

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String encodedString = "https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FURL%23Syntax";
      String decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(encodedString, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println(decodedString);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }

}
```

The result will be
[image]